# What is Ejs , What is the use of EJS?

Tags: node.js, ejs

Can anyone please explain what is Ejs , can we build a full fledge frontend using Ejs while using node.?
I have been searching for it but i can not find the answer i want.?And please someone differentiate between the frontend frameworks like (angular and react) and Ejs..

Comment: EJS is a template system.  You define HTML pages in the EJS syntax and you specify where various data will go in the page.  Then, your app combines data with the template and "renders" a complete HTML page where EJS takes your data and inserts it into the web page according to how you've defined the template.  For example, you could have a table of dynamic data from a database and you want EJS to generate the table of data according to your display rules.  It saves you from the drudgery of writing code to dynamically generate HTML based on data.

Comment: EJS also supports shared templates that can be inserted into other templates (e.g. for a common header/footer in your web pages) so you can specify that layout once and then use it in all your other templates rather than repeating that HTML over and over in all your pages.  This vastly simplifies maintenance and modifications since common content is defined in one place and then used in many other pages.

Comment: FYI, there are [dozens of competing template systems](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/template-engines.html) for use in node.js.  EJS is a popular one and people typically choose one based on features that match your needs, how their layout language fits what you want to use, what seems easiest to you to use, etc... I've used Pug, Handlebars, Nunjucks and EJS.  Nunjucks is my current favorite.

Comment: @jfriend00  your answer is very helpful, another thing i want to ask is , are we able to build a proper frontend using ejs.??

Comment: EJS (along with all the other competing template engines) allows you to generate full-blown HTML pages.  I'm not sure what else you think you need for a "proper front-end"?

Comment: @jfriend00 lets say i have 3-4 pages , home , about , contact , products.I want to build them with ejs and do the backend stuff using express.

Comment: Any one of the template engines listed in the link in my about comment can do that.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

EJS is a template system. You define HTML pages in the EJS syntax and you specify where various data will go in the page. Then, your app combines data with the template and "renders" a complete HTML page where EJS takes your data and inserts it into the web page according to how you've defined the template. For example, you could have a table of dynamic data from a database and you want EJS to generate the table of data according to your display rules. It saves you from the drudgery of writing code to dynamically generate HTML based on data.

EJS is compatible with Express for back-end use as it hooks into the View engine architecture that Express provides and lets you render web pages to the client with `res.render()` in Express.

FYI, there are [dozens of competing template systems](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/template-engines.html) for use in node.js. EJS is a popular one and people typically choose one based on features that match your needs, how their layout language fits what you want to use, what seems easiest to you to use, etc... I've used Pug, Handlebars, Nunjucks and EJS. Nunjucks is my current favorite.

EJS (along with all the other competing template engines) allows you to generate full-blown HTML pages which certainly enables a "proper front-end".

EJS is a tool for generating web pages that can include dynamic data and can share templated pieces with other web pages (such as common headers/footers).  It is not a front-end framework.  While EJS can be used by client-side Javascript to generate HTML on the client-side, it is more typically used by your back-end to generate web pages in response to some URL request.  EJS is not a client-side framework like Angular or React and does not dictate what client-side framework you do or don't use (if any).  It is mostly covers a separate solution space.

Comment: @ShehryarTanoli - Does this answer your question?

Comment: can someone comment on how ejs compare to svelte? I am a web technology noob hope this is not a bad question.